# configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing

Tags: autotools, configure, autoconf, automake

I am new to autotools and trying to learn it.  I encountered a problem while trying to run configure on an existing open source project and get this error:

```
./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
/home/myaccount/coding/Plotutils/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/home/kzhou/coding/Plotutils/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
```

I don't see any good posting for fixing this problem.  How to fix this problem?

Comment: Try searching for "missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option".

Answer (score 3):

This is usually caused by mispackaged sources, for instance if they checked in to the SCM the `configure` file but not the rest of the auxiliary files, or the source tarball was not generated by `make dist`.

A quick solution is to ensure all the Autotools are re-executed:

```
autoreconf -fi
```

this will re-generate `configure`, `Makefile.in` and so on, and bring a new set of auxiliary files. It needs `autoconf`, `automake` and possibly `libtool` packages installed though, so it might be a bit of overkill.

Answer (score 2):

When looking inside the missing file in the project directory it has

```
scriptversion=2009-04-28.21; # UTC
```

In my ubuntu system I found the script at

```
/usr/share/libtool/build-aux/missing
```

It's version is

```
scriptversion=2013-10-28.13; # UTC
```

Simply copy the newer version to your project will fix this problem:

```
cp /usr/share/libtool/build-aux/missing .
```

Comment: Don't copy the file that way, it might break stuff :( (API might not match what `Makefile` expect.)

Comment: I am new to this area, how was the missing file copied into the project?

Comment: If you use `cp` from a random version of libtool it might not match the rest of the generated autotools. See my answer below for the canonical solution.